# Call static content

Tags: java

I have this code from JavaFX application:

```
private static final ImageView ncpic;    
    static {
        ncpic = new ImageView(TabContent.class.getResource("/images/6.jpg").toExternalForm());
    }
```

I noticed that I can use this picture only once. When I use it twice the scene where I call it it's empty. How I can use this picture twice or more times?
Maybe this is caused by the static java method which I call to display the picture?

P.S quick example:

```
public class TabContent {

    private static final ImageView ncpic;    
        static {
            ncpic = new ImageView(TabContent.class.getResource("/images/6.jpg").toExternalForm());
        }

        private static StackPane generalConfiguration() {

            StackPane stack = new StackPane();
            stack.getChildren().addAll(ncpic);   // Add the picture and the Label
            return stack;
        }
}
```

I use it this way:
TabContent.generalConfiguration()
And second time in different Java Class.

Comment: How and where do you use it?

Comment: Try by making it non-static. And that's not a method. It's a static initialization block.

Comment: In my case the java method is called many times. It should be static.

Comment: Make the static variable be the result of getExternalForm (whatever type that is), and call `new ImageView` every time you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why Only One ImageView Displays**

An [ImageView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) is a Node.  You can only ever have a single instance of a Node in a SceneGraph.  See the [Node documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region,
>   etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the
>   root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from
>   its former parent.

**How to Fix It**

If you want to share image data among multiple nodes, you can do so. For example.

```
private static final Image ncpic = new Image(
  TabContent.class.getResource(
    "/images/6.jpg"
  ).toExternalForm()
);
```

Note, there is no need for a static block for just a single initialization statement.

Also note that the above code will work in under Java 7, but [may fail under the current Java 8 early access release](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30796).  You will be assured that the code will work in Java 8 if the JavaFX system has first been initialized before your static code runs (e.g. the init or start method of your application has been executed previously).

Whenever you want to reuse the Image, just wrap it in a new ImageView before you add it to the Scene.  For example:

```
pane1.add(new ImageView(ncpic));
pane2.add(new ImageView(ncpic));
```

Now the image will show in both pane1 and pane2, rather than just in pane2 as it would if you tried to reuse a single static ImageView instance.

**Sample Code**

The sample code from Peter's question can be rewritten as below to function correctly:

```
public class TabContent {
  private static final Image ncpic = new Image(
    TabContent.class.getResource(
      "/images/6.jpg"
    ).toExternalForm()
  );

  private static StackPane generalConfiguration() {
    StackPane stack = new StackPane(); 
    stack.getChildren().addAll(new ImageView(ncpic));  

    return stack;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to clone that object before you draw it:

```
class ImageManager {
    public static ImageView imageView;

    static {
        imageView = new ImageView(...);
    }

   public static ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView.clone();
    }
}
```

There's a chance that method clone() will pass the same data reference to this new instance instead of creating it again. So it'll be a new object, but with the same resources.

Comment: `imageView.clone()` does not compile as the `clone()` method has protected (not public) access. I don't think cloning JavaFX scene graph nodes is supported by the JavaFX scene graph anyway.